# Finding tree canopy width using PDAL?

Tags: lidar, classification, point-cloud, pdal, canopy-height-model

I want to classify (and separate) houses from trees (high vegetation) in point cloud data using PDAL.

I use height filter for this purpose. Our high Vegetation lies in the range between 5 and 10 meters. So, I apply filter of range 5m to 10m.

The filter output gives me few houses and all of trees.

I think we can differentiate these remaining tree from houses using tree canopy width; however, is there any filter which can differentiate trees from houses?

Here is my filter details:

```
{
  "pipeline":[
    "./ground_non_ground.las",
    {
      "type":"filters.hag"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.ferry",
      "dimensions":"HeightAboveGround = Z"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.range",
      "limits":"Z[5:10]"
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.las",
      "filename":"./tree.las"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two additional options to identify trees from canopy height models. Both of these options will identify (mostly) trees, which you can then use as a mask to isolate buildings.

- `find_trees` in the R lidR package. There is a good tutorial on [tree
  segmentation](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Segment-individual-trees-and-compute-metrics-(Part-2)) from the author of the package.
- [FUSION](https://web.archive.org/web/20170623192930/http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html)'s TreeSeg algorithm (p.138 [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170426145323/http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/FUSION_manual.pdf))

Answer (score 7):

First, for the answers proposed here, you probably do not want to use the ferry filter to push `HeightAboveGround` to `Z`, at least not prior to segmentation, as the act of normalizing heights involves subtracting an interpolated estimate of the ground elevation from each return. Something planar in the original `X, Y, Z` space may no longer be planar in the transformed `X, Y, HeightAboveGround` space. If you really need this to occur for downstream processing, I'd suggest holding off until the end of the pipeline.

Two options in the PDAL toolbox are:

- `filters.approximatecoplanar`
- `filters.estimaterank`

Neither of these is a full-fledged building/vegetation segmentation solution, but may serve as valuable building blocks.

PDAL's [`approximatecoplanar`](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.approximatecoplanar.html) filter may be helpful -- it is just one of the processing steps used in "Real-Time Detection of Planar Regions in Unorganized Point Clouds" by Limberger and Oliveira. Try adding the following to your pipeline following the existing range filter.

```
{
  "type":"filters.approximatecoplanar",
  "knn":8,
  "thresh1":25,
  "thresh2":6
},
```

You will have a new dimension called `Coplanar`, where 0 indicates that a point is not likely part of a planar patch (e.g., vegetation) and 1 indicates that it is perhaps part of a planar patch (e.g., roof). You'll need to either 1) pick another output format that supports the `Coplanar` dimension, or 2) insert another range filter to select only `Coplanar=0` or `Coplanar=1`.

The [`estimaterank`](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.estimaterank.html) filter is similar in nature. There you will get a new dimension `Rank`, where `Rank=2` indicates planar features and `Rank=3` would be more indicative of vegetation. Again, you'll need to choose how to deal with your new dimension as the LAS writer will drop unknown fields like `Rank`.